# Create a Dropdown Button from a list of maps

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a dropdown button using a list of maps.

This is my list which is in `_location['category']`:

```
[{id: 12345, title: My category}]
```

And the DropdownButton:

```
          DropdownButton(
            items: _location['category'].map((item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item['title']),
                value: item.id,
              );
            }),
            onChanged: (newVal) => print(newVal),
            value: null,
          ),
```

Error: `The following _TypeError was thrown building LocationDialog(dirty, state: _LocationDialogState#6947a):
type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Null>>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.toList()` to make your `.map` a List.
The code below should help

Create a `List` called `category` somewhere then use it with the `DropdownButton`

```dart
List category = _location['category'];
```

```dart
          DropdownButton(
            items: category.map((item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item['title']),
                value: item.id,
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (newVal) => print(newVal),
            value: null,
          ),
```

Comment: `The following _TypeError was thrown building LocationDialog(dirty, state: _LocationDialogState#14a2a):
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Null>>'`

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!